# connect a java web application to both oracle and teradata db

Tags: java, oracle, teradata

I have an existing java web app that is currently connected to an Oracle db, I need to also connect this application to a teradata db where it will run scripts based on which db needs to be used. I have never worked with a teradata db before, and just need a little help with setting up my application to use the teradata db along with the existing db. Any tutorials and/or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that from the amount of information provided I can only answer with a list of steps which should be done, but finding the exact answer will be up to you.

- Make sure your database is configured correctly. Check if the database is reachable and if you have an account set up which will be used by the application to access it.
- Googling "[your database name] with [your application name]" most often yields complete tutorials on how to set up the connection from the application
- Make sure your application knows *how* to communicate with the database - check if you have the correct driver in the right folder.
- Configure data sources for your application. I presume that in the same place where the OracleDB connection is defined should be the TeradataDB defined.
- Try, check the application log, fix the specific problem, rinse, repeat until you reach the database.

Check out:

[Teradata JDBC Driver Sample Programs](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samplePrograms.html)

[hello world example to connect teradata through jdbc](http://www.egtry.com/java/database/jdbc/hello_teradata)

[How To Work With Teradata Using Java?](http://ezinearticles.com/?How-To-Work-With-Teradata-Using-Java?&id=1110940)

It might be more effective if you post a specific problem, which you are experiencing.